# htaccess / Typo3 in subfolder - exclude other folders in root

Tags: .htaccess, dns, directory, typo3, subdirectory

I don't really understand the structur of htaccess but I'll try to explain the problem the best I can.

I have a Typo3 page inside a folder in my _root directory named "typo" and inside is the htaccess that defines the realurl navigation. If I check the site with "www.mypage.com/typo" everything looks and works fine.

Now the thing is, that inside the _root there are other subfolder with webcontent and once I change the domain directory (so that the Typo3 page is the main index-page) I can't open the other websites inside the folders anymore.

for example: "www.mypage.com/otherwebstuff" just gives me a Typo3 error.

I googled for the last hour but wasn't successful. Is there no simple way to tell htaccess to simply ignore my other folders?

This is my current htacess file inside my Typo3 directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^/test/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/ - [L]
#RewriteRule ^/test/typo3$ /test/typo3/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: You are probably missing a "RewriteBase"-directive in your .htaccess. Try to add the line `RewriteBase /typo/` (maybe a slash less?) after the `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but now I'm getting a Internal Server Error - I guess now realurl is acting up. I changed the baseURL inside typoscript but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend mapping a subdomain to the directory TYPO3 lives in:

```
typo.mypage.com -> mypage.com/typo
```

You will run into way less problems and conflicts.

Comment: btw, it's nicer to keep the "3" when referring to TYPO3; if you can't name it typo3, you can name it t3

Comment: This would have been my plan B - but I guess this way is really the safest isnt it? Thanks for the tip. :-)